# Does the google app engine blobstore automatically compress the data it stores?

Tags: google-app-engine, compression, blobstore

Does the google app engine blobstore automatically compress the data it stores? I mean the stored data, not when serving to clients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blobstore is a GAE service which you use through a public API. The internal implementation is not disclosed.

But, why would this matter? The data you put in is the same data you get out.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wasn't thinking about this clearly. Thanks. :)